# Why does my custom PC monitor go into sleep and then turn back on its own repeatedly?

Tags: windows-10, display, operating-systems, sleep

I just assembled my PC last week but I came across a petty yet annoying problem: after the turn-off-display timer is reached, the system does turn off the monitor. But rather than go into standby mode, the monitor would turn it back on one second later, with black blank screen on it and the signal sign on the top left corner. It then goes into a cycle of on/off endlessly.

I'm pretty sure the problem does not lie with the monitor, as when the system goes into sleep, the monitor does go into standby mode properly. And if connected through HDMI port instead of DisplayPort, such problem won't happen.

I've tried everything from updating the drivers and OS, to disable overclocking, but nothing so far worked. I now use a makeshift workaround: set turn-off-monitor-timer to never and use sleep instead. But I really need to solve this. Please help me with this. Thanks!

Here's the specification of my PC: i7-6700K, Gigabyte Z170 Gaming 7, Intel Integrated graphic, Samsung U28E590D 4K monitor.

Comment: Here's the specification of my PC: i7-6700K, Gigabyte Z170 Gaming 7, Intel Integrated graphic, Samsung U28E590D 4K monitor.

Comment: You can edit that information into your question using the links just below the question tags.

Comment: Does your display still have power when you use sleep? Is there more than one signal source/cable connected?

Comment: Does your monitor have a powersaver function? If so, does it solves the problem if you change that setting?

Comment: 1. Yes, the monitor still has power when the computer enters into sleep mode. It just enters into standby mode as expected, with the blue indicator light flickering as normal. 2. No, I only hooked one device to the monitor, which is my PC. 3. Yes, it does have an Eco mode. But when I turned it on, except making the displayer dimmer, it does nothing which helps the problem.

Comment: 4. I also changed three DP cables but the problem was the same.

Comment: What DP version is your monitor set to use? [This](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/geforce-graphics-cards/5/235122/monitor-wont-go-to-sleep-displayport-fixed/) suggests it needs to be >=1.2 for sleep to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect the monitor using HDMI instead of DP it won't happen but then you get a horrible refresh rate of 30Hz.

I read somewhere (I cannot find it now) that when the video output goes to sleep the voltage is cut and the monitor is not doing the same so the video output thinks a new monitor has been added and then it enters into a loop.